# Mistakes in htaccess redirects?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am a beginner with htaccess stuff and need help checking for mistakes in my htaccess codes below ?
I have 3 set of redirect codes and wondering if they interfere with each other ?
Also wondering if I have redundant redirect code.

Also specifically within the "Stop Hotlinking Code", is this RewriteCond correct?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)%{HTTP_HOST}/.*$ [NC]
```

My goal is to KEEP the `www` and `trailing slash` for my URLs , and to remove the `index.html` for my URLs 
Here is my .htaccess File

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

#Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301] 

#Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]

#Redirect index.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R=301,L]

#Stop Hotlinking
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)%{HTTP_HOST}/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|xml|php|png|css|pdf)$ - [F]
```

.

---

**Edit:**

---

**Questions:**
-Is my updated htaccess below correct?
-Do I put `RewriteBase /` at the top or keep it as is (one with the `# Begin WordPress` rules and a second `RewriteBase /` with `# Force Trailing Slash` ?
-Do I need `Options +FollowSymLinks` and if yes where do I put this?

Notice that I:
-removed the `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteBase /` from WordPress rules and kept it at the top
-put WordPress Rules BELOW redirects
-removed end slashes for `#Redirect non-www to www` and `#Redirect index.html`

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect index.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force Trailing Slash
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301] 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# Stop Hotlinking
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)domain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|xml|php|png|css|pdf)$ - [F]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not correct. You can't have `%` variables or back references in the regex part of the condition. You *could* use a regex backreference though. Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:::%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^:]+):::http://(www\.)\1/.*$ [NC]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I guess I should not tweak with htaccess code. Originally this was the code I found in google: ----- RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)domain.com/.*$ [NC] ---- Is this RewriteCond correct regarding the Stop Hotlinking code? ---------- Also, did you notice any mistakes with my other htaccess codes above? Does the 3 set of redirects interfere with each other?

Comment: @leko if you know what your hostname is going to be, then `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)domain.com/.*$ [NC]` is fine. THe problem with your other redirects is that they all append a `/` at the end.

Comment: Jon regarding "problem with your other redirects is that they all append a / at the end" ---- Actually, the original code did NOT have a slash at the end. I added the end slash myself because I thought I was supposed to keep it consistent with the "Force Trailing Slash" RewriteRule. Is my logic incorrect? Should I keep the end slash or remove it (regarding #Redirect non-www to www) (and regarding #Redirect index.html) ?

Comment: @leko no, you'll just end up getting redirected to URLs with lots of slashes, You only want to add the slash when you are matching a request that is missing it (the force trailign slash rule) also, you want all your redirects before your wordpress rules.

Comment: Jon, appreciate your help. Can you check for mistakes in my updated htaccess (see edit above) ? And do I put `RewriteBase /` at the top or keep it as is (one with with the #Begin WordPress rules and a second `RewriteBase /` with `# Force Trailing Slash` ? Also, do I need `Options +FollowSymLinks` and if yes where do I put this?

Comment: @leko looks fine, but you still need to test it. Mod_rewrite won't work at all without `FollowSymLinks`, so if you aren't getting an error, it's already turned on so you don't need to do anything

Comment: Jon, just to be sure, am I allowed to have TWO `RewriteBase /` (see line 12 and line 19) ?

Comment: @leko yeah, that's fine, as long as they're the same it doesn't make any difference